# How to remove the scrollbar in Nuxt + vuetify?

Tags: css, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I basicaly want to remove the scrollbar:

on vuetify they say to use

```
html { overflow-y: auto }
```

But on Nuxt this doesn't work ?

if someone know I would be grateful.

My code : layouts/default.vue

```
<template>
 <v-app dark>
   <v-main>
     <nuxt />
   </v-main>
 </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style scoped>
html { overflow-y: auto } // <=== doesn't work

.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.page-enter,
.page-leave-to {
 opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `overflow-y: auto` wont hide anything

Comment: hidden doesn't too so : /

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: auto` only hide the scrollbar when the content height is less than container height, you need to use CSS/SCSS to style the scrollbar with `display: none` properties.

You can style the scrollbar using `::webkit-scrollbar` selector, change the color, or width and height, or just add `display: none` to hide it. But, it has compatibility issues, it works almost everywhere except Mozilla. Instead mozilla style its scrollbar using `scrollbar-color, scrollbar-width`.

Here is the documentation:

- ::webkit-scrollbar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar
- scrollbar-color https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars